# How to "install" Fedora / Opensuse on USB Drive

Tags: linux, usb, fedora, opensuse

I want to install dedicated(no live CD) Fedora / Opensuse on USB key. I have a sony micro vault click(32 GB) usb drive. The previous answer is not working fine for me (trouble installing Fedora 21 on USB drive).

Comment: Could you live boot onto one USB and then install it to the USB that you want to boot from?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an another live CD/USB, which you boot into. Following which simply run the install program from there (either straight from the bootup menu or in the live system).

[image: img]

Comment: I had used another USB to run fedora live and tried to install it on my micro vault. But still the screen hangs on fedora bootup screen.

Comment: Booting to the live OS from another USB doesn't work for you? Try the text mode installer? Also, how are you installing the live system to the other usb drive?